# what is the gcc option for add header file in complie time?

Tags: gcc

How to compile this code?

```
  /* main.c file*/

   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int c;
       c = add(5,5);
       printf("sum is %d\n",c);

       return 0;
   }
```

Add.c(in same directory)

```
   /*add.c*/
    int add(int a, int b)
    {
        int c;
        c = a + b;

        return c;
    }
```

Add.h(in same directory)

```
  /* add.h file*/

   int add(int, int);
```

Then i am create a object file for add.c

```
$ gcc -c -Wall add.c -I.
```

Then i am try to create a object file for main.c

```
$ gcc -c -Wall main.c -I.
main.c:6:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘add’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
c = add(5, 5);
    ^
```

Please any one tell, how to give the headfile name in compiling time.

Comment: `-include Add.h` but why not just edit the file to `#include "Add.h"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

you can either use `#include "Add.h"` at the top of your `main.c` (this is the preferred route), or you can use the `-include` command line flag (this is discouraged because it does not scale and is not portable):

```
gcc -c -Wall main.c -I. -include Add.h
```